# Log in system .txt file reading issues

Tags: java, authentication

So I am trying to make a log in system which stores the usernames and password in a .txt file and when you log in it reads them and checks if the entered value and the value in the .txt file are matching. Unfortunately whenever i try to check is the input-ed value same as the value in the .txt file (is the entered username same as the username in the .txt file which I use as my database) i get a negative answer so here is the bugged part of the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        LineNumberReader LineReader = null;
        try {
            LineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("C:/Documents and Settings/Josip/Desktop/PROGRAMING MOTHAFUKAZ/JAVA/Login/DataBaza.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String UserName = username.getText();
        System.out.println(UserName);



        try {
            String Line = LineReader.readLine();

            while(Line != null){

                UserName = username.getText();
                System.out.println(Line);
                Line = LineReader.readLine();

                if(Line == UserName){
                    System.out.println("LOGIN SUCCESFUL");
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 



    }
```

the username object is the JTextField

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

`if (Line == UserName)` 
You are comparing reference of Line and UserName

 To check contents use

```
if (Line.contentEquals(UserName))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Check the string comparison instaed of **"==" use ".equalsIgnoreCase() or equals()"**
2. Readina text file is always problematic because even space is also considered as character while reading so use **trim()** before comparing the Username and Line to get that type of the errors.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Line == UserName
```

Use equals not == for string in java

Also you are setting userName value everytime you read a new line. I don't think you need it.

Comment: i set the userName value just in case that wasn't the problem but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The Line == UserName is wrong.
You should use " == " only when you compare numbers.
For Strings you should use Line.equals(UserName) or even Line.equalsIgnoreCase(UserName).